# iOS app crash when trying to log NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog, theos, cydia-substrate

I have a problem where I try to log NSDictionary content and as soon as the method is called the app crashes.

This is the code I have tried after advice from a talented "hacker":

```
%hook UserData
-(int)getVariable:(NSDictionary *)fp8 {

for (NSString *key in [fp8 allKeys]) {
%log(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [fp8 objectForKey:key]);

}
return %orig;
}
%end
```

also tried:

```
%hook UserData
-(int)getVariable {

int originalValue = %orig;

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
NSError *error;

[[fp8 description] writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lol_%d.txt",basePath,fp8.count] atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

return %orig;

}

%end
```

Both ways result in a crash of the app. This is on a iphone 4 with ios 6.1.3 tethered JB.

```
 DoD EN[1000]: -[__NSCFConstantString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2a7a88
 DoD EN[1000]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2a7a88'
    *** First throw call stack:
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on what may be wrong here?

Comment: On what line does the app crash? What is the error reason given for the crash (EXEC_BAD_ACCESS? Something else?) Also, what are the "%" signs in your code supposed to represent? I've never seen that before in this context.

Comment: You say it crashes but don't provide any error message.

Comment: And note that you're not logging an NSDictionary, but rather an entry from one.

Comment: The app crash after the dylib that is compiled with this hook of the getVariable function is loaded.

The % signs is from theos

Comment: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Logos

Comment: just some good-natured advice: you dabble in things you don't get .. very basic things. before trying stuff like hooking into other apps Id ask you to start with the basics

Answer (score 2):

The crash log provide quite an explanation

```
-[__NSCFConstantString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2a7a88
```

I guess this is the crash log associated with the first piece of code you posted :

```
%hook UserData
-(int)getVariable:(NSDictionary *)fp8 {

    for (NSString *key in [fp8 allKeys]) {
        %log(@"key: %@, value: %@ \n", key, [fp8 objectForKey:key]);
    }
    return %orig;
}
%end
```

It crashes at the execution of `[fp8 allKeys]`, claiming that `allKeys` is not a valid selector for objects of class `__NSCFConstantString`
What it tells you is that `fp8` is *not* an `NSDictionary*` but rather a `__NSCFConstantString*` (that is, a pointer to a constant instance of `NSString` such as one defined like `NSString* foo = @"bar"`).

If that is true, then the second code you posted would crash also because `count` is not a valid selector for class `NSString`.

Why don't you just try the following, see what it gives you :

```
%hook UserData
-(int)getVariable:(id)fp8 {

    %log(@"fp8: %@ : %@\n", NSStringFromClass([fp8 class]), [fp8 description]);

    return %orig;
}
%end
```

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed a NSString :)

Comment: Glad I could help. In that case, you might wanna mark the above answer as accepted. Out of curiosity : what are you trying to do swizzling those methods ?

Answer (score 0):

If you print the description it should work. Following Way :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary description]);
```

Comment: Not sure how to use this info, sorry for being unclear. The code above is a hook into a function of a app I dont have the sourcecode for. Its reverse engineering so to speak.